# Can I access directly to the second value of an array after .split()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code :

```
var tmp=$(this).attr('id').split("_");
```

and I'd like to store on tmp the second value after the split. So if $(this).attr('id') = "hello_marco" I'd like to store in tmp the value marco, not the array.

Of course, I want to do it directly in one line of code, without first store the array and the access to it with array[1].

Is it possible on JS/Jquery?

Comment: Don't use `.attr()` to get the ID. Just do `this.id.split("_")`. [Here's a jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-attr-id-vs-dom-id-prop) that illustrates the impact of over-using jQuery like this.

Comment: ...actually the difference is even greater in this case because you're having to create a jQuery object as well. [jsPerf test.](http://jsperf.com/jquery-attr-id-vs-dom-id-prop/2)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
var tmp = $(this).attr('id').split("_")[1];
```

Comment: As I was writing my answer, the notification came up "three new answers have been posted".

Answer (score 3):

```
var tmp = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
//                                     ^^^
```

Split returns an array, so just dereference the array.

Answer (score 3):

Just add it to the end

```
var tmp=$(this).attr('id').split("_")[1];
```

it's not probably best practice but it works

Comment: It's great practice. Idiomatic all the way.

Answer (score 1):

```
var tmp = $(this).attr('id').split("_")[1];
```