# Filter href for hash value using jquery

Tags: jquery, hash, replace

Is it possible to filer the value of the href for just the hash value.

```
<a class="menu" href="/folder/#test">Test</a>
```

I'm trying to get just the value of the hash "#test"

```
var item = $($(a.menu).attr("href"));
   item.pathname.replace(/^\//,'');
```

Thanks

Comment: split the string using `#` as delimiter and take the 2nd value...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390091/can-i-access-directly-to-the-second-value-of-an-array-after-split#